# "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" error

Tags: oracle10g

i am getting `"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"` error in the following code:

```
SELECT sname
FROM sailors AS s, reserves AS r
WHERE bid=102 AND s.sid=r.sid;
```

Comment: Which table is bid in, or is it in both? try specifying it as either r.bid or s.bid.

Comment: Don't need the `as`, just `select sname from sailors s,reserves r ...`

Comment: You should also start using explicit `JOIN` instead of the outdated implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, you do not use `AS` to provide table aliases.  You just specify the alias.  Optionally, you can use `AS` to provide column aliases

```
SELECT sname
  FROM sailors s,
       reserves r
 WHERE s.sid = r.sid
   AND bid = 102
```